# Rails - any fancy ways to handle 404s?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, http-status-code-404

I have a rails app I built for an old site I converted from another cms (in a non-rails language, hehe). Most of the old pages are mapped to the new pages using routes.rb. But there are still a few 404s.

I am a rails newb so I'm asking if there are any advanced ways to handle 404s. For example, if I was programming in my old language I'd do this:

- Get the URL (script_name) that was being accessed and parse it.
- Do a lookup in the database for any keywords, ids, etc found in the new URL.
- If found, redirect to the page (or if multiple records are found, show them all on a results page and let user choose). With rails I'd probably want to do :status => :moved_permanently I'm guessing?
- If not found, show a 404.

Are there any gems/plugins or tutorials you know of that would handle such a thing, if it's even possible. Or can you explain on a high level how that can be done? I don't need a full code sample, just a push in the right direction.

PS. It's a simple rails 3 app that uses a single Content model.

Comment: About your 'P.S.', models have nothing, really nothing to do with routing. Controllers take care of that. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Put this in routes (after every other route that you have, this will capture every url)

```
match '*url' => 'errors#routing'
```

And now in errors controller in routing action you can implement any fancy logic that you want, and render a view as always (you might want to add `:status => 404` to the `render` call).  Requested url will be available in controller as `params[:url]`.

Comment: Wicked, this is just what I was looking for to get me headed in the right direction. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is an ugly way of doing this:

```
render :file => "#{RAILS_ROOT}/public/404.html", :layout => false, :status => 404
```

Maybe someone can come with a better solution.